# Strip Queries from URLS in Google Data Studio with REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I'm trying to build a new calculated field in Google Data Studio to get rid of all the queries. I've tried the following formula:

`REGEXP_REPLACE(page,"\?(.*)","")`

But Data Studio return me an invalid formula... I guess that's because It's not `Google RE2`. how do I translate this into `Google RE2`?

Comment: Try double escaping `?`. The regex itself is a valid RE2 pattern. It would be helpful if you also provided some sample string and expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(page,"[?].*","")
```

The pattern will be parsed as a literal `?` followed with any 0+ chars, and the whole match will get replaced with an empty string.