# Google Analytics - grouping Page

Tags: google-analytics, trailing-slash

I've been reading a lot about grouping page on Google Analytics but haven't figured out a clear answer to a problem.

My issue is this one :

[Same pages but one with / and other without /](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4b3Q.png)

Basically, when I read my analytics I have two different entry for the same page, because some external links send people to one entry without the trailing slash (lets call it Page1), on others send people to url with the trailing slash (Page2).
It's a bit anoying when reading the stats, because you have to add up these two pages to have a clear view about what's going on.

I tried one option: add filters that remove the trailing slash. With this, I was able to get all the statistics on Page 1. It was a simple filter ([Search and replace filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEECO.png)) that was grouping the two pages.
However, looking back at this option, It created another problem: this filter is not retroactive, which means when I will look at Page1, I will have stats from the day I applied this filter, whereas Page2 will score 0 from this exact same date. A small picture to make that clear:

[Statistics on Page2 with Slash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeofx.png)

[Statistics on Page1 filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geAda.png)

Clearly here there is a discontinuity on my stats. To check long term datas I have to select another page, and to check new data I have to check the page without the trailing slash.

I removed this filter because it's very difficult to read data right now, and I'm looking for a solution to groupe these two pages so my data will be readable...

Thank you very much for you help,

Michael

Edit: I'm on Wordpress, maybe a way there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing you can do within Google Analytics. I suggest you create your reports in [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/), which is free, and which allows you to aggregate Urls by using regular expressions to find matching parts ([example e.g. in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45934988/strip-queries-from-urls-in-google-data-studio-with-regexp-replace)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Eike !